# nav bar hide changes size of background and images

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I am currently working on an app that uses multiple `UIViewController`s with a single `UINavigationController` at the start. I am happy with the `UINavigationBar` on the first 2 `UIViewControllers` but on the third one I have it hiding when I press play and reaper when I press pause.

When it hides and reappears it changes the size of my background and image I have on there its as though the background and image are sized to the bottom line of the `UINavigationBar`.

Can anyone help with this so the bar is floating above the background and when it disappears it doesn't alter the sizes.

This is the code I'm using to hide and unhide the bar:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this in the auto layout and reset the constraints to not attach to the nav bar but the top instead.